# Lua Table - Search for Items that starts with an Letter

Tags: lua, lua-table

i have this table

```
    animals = {
     {sname = "bunny", name = "bunny hase", size = 4, size2 = 8, size3 = 9},
     {sname = "mouse", name = "Micky Mouse", size = 1, size2 = 12, size3 = 22},
     {sname = "cow", name = "Die Kuh", size = 30, size2 = 33, size3 = 324
}
```

there i can search by a listed entry

```
for _,v in pairs(animals) do
  if v.sname == "bunny" then
    print(v.sname, v.name, v.size, v.size2, v.size3)
    break
  end
end
```

and get the result:

```
bunny   bunny hase  4   8   9
```

Now i want to search in my table by starting with a single Letter, for example "b", that show me all the entries starting with the letter "b" to get the same result?

I found no Solution. May you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The table `animals` needs a trailing `}` ;-)

Put it in a `Lua -i` console and play around with...

```
>animals = {                                   
     {sname = "bunny", name = "bunny hase", size = 4, size2 = 8, size3 = 9},
     {sname = "mouse", name = "Micky Mouse", size = 1, size2 = 12, size3 = 22},
     {sname = "cow", name = "Die Kuh", size = 30, size2 = 33, size3 = 324}
}
-- Now set a __call metamethod on same table
>setmetatable(animals,{__call=function(tab,...)
local args={...}
for key, value in pairs(tab) do
if value.sname:find(args[1],1) then print(key,'=',value.sname) end
end
end})
table: 0x565c4a00
-- Lets try it once
>animals('b')                                  
1    =    bunny
-- Next one
>animals('c')
3    =    cow
-- Last one
>animals('m')
2    =    mouse
```

Using metatables holds your stuff together.
Another fine place is the `__index` metamethod that can hold all functions you need for that table and can be used like the string functions on a string.
( Like: `value.sname:find(args[1],1)` )
This leads to the heart of what find should do.
In first example it looks in whole `sname` for a matching pattern.
Check the Lua patterns what also can be useful.
Maybe a `^` only for the begining sounds smart?
So construct the find pattern: `'^'..args[1]`
...and use more than one letter if you have a cow, crow, frog and fish in your animals.

Example with function name `find` in `__index`

```
>animals = {                                   
     {sname = "bunny", name = "bunny hase", size = 4, size2 = 8, size3 = 9},
     {sname = "mouse", name = "Micky Mouse", size = 1, size2 = 12, size3 = 22},
     {sname = "cow", name = "Die Kuh", size = 30, size2 = 33, size3 = 324}
}
-- Place a find function into __index
>setmetatable(animals,{__index={find=function(tab,...)
local args={...}
for key, value in pairs(tab) do
if value.sname:find('^'..args[1]) then print(key,'=',value.sname) end
end
end}})
table: 0x565c3db0
-- first
>animals:find('c')                                
3       =       cow
-- next
>animals:find('m')
2       =       mouse
-- last
>animals:find('b')
1       =       bunny
```

If you like to print all key values then extend the `print()` in `find()`.

Comment: `v` and `k` are backwards in your loop definitions. `v` is usually used for the `value` and `k` for the `key`

Comment: Yes you are right - Lazyness let me do this instead of readable and understandable words - I correct it for following reader - Thanks for  the hint

Answer (score 0):

Stop, i found an issue....

Look here - i prefer the first solution:

```
animals = {                                   
     {sname = "bunny", name = "bunny hase", size = 4, size2 = 8, size3 = 9},
     {sname = "mouse", name = "Micky Mouse", size = 1, size2 = 12, size3 = 22},
     {sname = "cow", name = "Die Kuh", size = 30, size2 = 33, size3 = 324}
}
-- Now set a __call metamethod on same table
setmetatable(animals,{__call=function(tab,...)
local args={...}
for v,k in pairs(tab) do
if k.sname:find(args[1],1) then print(v,'=',k.sname) end
end
end})


-- Search Entries with Start U.....
-- there should be no result, but....
animals('u')
```

i get the Result:
1   =   bunny
2   =   mouse

that should not be the result!

Comment: Read the text between my two examples and try second example - The magic is done with the pattern construction

Comment: The ```^```  can be hardcoded in the find function or you give it as argument. The second case lets first example work with: ```animals('^o')``` - Output is of course nothing then - Also try ```^%l``` for lowercase and ```^%u``` for capital letters